# Asking time is later than closing time

Tags: bug, status-deferred, closing, asking

So I just encountered [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374923/what-weapon-is-the-strongest-in-minecraft) and it seems like something's off:

[image: Times aren't correct]

As it turns out, the asking time seems to be quite later than the closing time and it's strange considering that this isn't logical.

The question being asked on August 22 last year, and for the next 4-5 days, it got closed, so it's weird how the asking time is later than the closing time.

Is there some problem with the relative time calculation going wrong?

Comment: Yeah this appears to be a discrepancy with the relative time calculation. If you hover over each of the relative times it shows the correct absolute times (asked 2020-08-22, closed 2020-08-27), and the timeline is also correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to incorrect rounding. It has been partially fixed, but only for years: [Post was closed before it even existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344532/295232) is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

I think your particular case might be the same as this meta SE bug report:
[Inconsistent rounding of "months ago"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347355/295232) which is currently [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - according to JNat♦ (Community Manager at SE) there are no current plans to address it.